# my website is messed up i might have goofed up with some files

Tags: magento2.3

i have messed up something with my website.. i was searching some header and footer files and might have changed something in hurry..
now website looks like shit.
https://preyanksolar.in
somebody can please help.. will be appreciated greatly.
[image]

Comment: Hey, might be hard to tell what happened, but check vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less, did you changed this file? You can try to go to git and download the original to replace. All the code you see in there is from that file. Check the name, if it's a .less things like that

Comment: hey thanks for the help.. but i did removed comments - / /** // * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. // * See COPYING.txt for license details. // */ just to check if thats whats showing up on my site but to my surprise, its not whats showing up on home page.. I am not sure whats messed up. also i couldn't fild that file on git either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Looking into it I can say that you have did changes in some file related to footer.

Please use this command `find /to/target/directory* -mtime -1` if you did changes 2 day before then replace 1 with no. of day and then you can see which file you have change

and then replace those file with backup file or default file of magento

Comment: thank you so much but that didn't help much i checked all those checked files.. it happened just few hrs ago.. i am sure i might have changed something by mistake but not sure what

Comment: Then u can use this find /to/target/directory* -mmin -30 or 30 and 30 is in minute

Answer (score 0):

Thank you brother Nilesh..
I couldn't properly understand/execute your comment but after figuring it out.. It worked out perfectly fine..
No words to thank you enough. I am very grateful.